# creating a st_contains query with geographies not geometries

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection

I'm trying to find all the geography points that are contained in a geography polygon, let say all the traffic lights within a given city or neighborhoods,

how can i convert this working st_intersect query to work with contained and remain with geographies not geometries

```
select count(*) from table1
where table1.UniqueID in (
SELECT table1.UniqueID
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON ST_Intersects(table1.point, table2.polygon)
where table2.UniqueID = 2);
```

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. What have you already looked at? What have you already tried? What worked? What didn't work the way you expected, and what happened instead? What version of postgis? Those are important bits of information you can add by clicking edit below the question. Otherwise, the answer is just "http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html says it works with geography, so what is the problem with what you already have?"

Answer (score 3):

For the point/polygons case, ST_Contains and ST_Intersects are equivalent.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Do you have some reference to the docs? And do you know maybe if ST_CoveredBy would suit better? https://postgis.net/docs/ST_CoveredBy.html